# How to calculate an avarage time value of all selected datasets?

Tags: mongodb

There are multiple documents in my db with this structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7f6a937563a63c1d8b4639"),
    "admission" : ISODate("2019-09-16T10:27:20.197Z"),
    "target" : [
        {
            "score" : 3
        },
    {
            "score" : 2
        }
    ],
    "contact" : {
        "user" : "user",
        "time" : ISODate("2019-09-16T10:47:20.197Z")
    }
}
```

I need to select all datasets with the `score` of 3 as a first element of `target` and return the average time difference between `admission` and `contact.time`.

So the result should be something like: *342 datasets with score of 3 have an average time difference of 25.34 minutes*

So the first part should be easy by doing

```
db.data.find({ 'target.0': 2 })
```

But how do I get the avarage time difference from all these selected datasets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) to do this. Based on your data format, you need `target.0.score` instead of `target.0`

```
db.data.aggregate([
{
    $match : {"target.0.score": 3} // Filter All targets
},
{
    $group : {
        "_id" : null,
        "Datasets" : {$sum : 1},
        "Average" : {"$avg" : {$divide: [{$subtract: ["$contact.time", "$admission"]}, 60000]}} // Calculate Average from distance, also, Divide by 60000 to convert from milliseconds to seconds. 
    }
}
])
```

The result document will be as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "Datasets" : 3.0,
    "Average" : 26.6666666666667
}
```

Comment: But with that I don't get the output how many datasets are used to calculate the average

Comment: Updated the answer. It's a `{$sum : 1}` to get the count of dataset